# set database and collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I set my database and collection using mongoose ? I am trying to connect to a mongodb atlas database using mongoose. My database is called "test_db" and collection name is "users" where would I specify that information ?

This is my shema (data.js):

```
// /backend/data.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// this will be our data base's data structure 
const DataSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    password: String
  }
);

// export the new Schema so we could modify it using Node.js
module.exports = mongoose.model("users", DataSchema);
```

and this is server.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const Data = require('./data');

const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const router = express.Router();

// this is our MongoDB database
const dbRoute = 'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-bmihj.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
  ;

// connects our back end code with the database
const conn = mongoose.connect(dbRoute, { useNewUrlParser: true });

//let db = mongoose.connection;
const db = conn.db('test_db');

var MyModel = mongoose.model('Test', new Schema({ name: String }));

db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to the database'));

// checks if connection with the database is successful
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));


// this is our get method
// this method fetches all available data in our database
router.get('/getData', (req, res) => {
  Data.find((err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
    return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Through this line, you are connected to MongoDB:

`const conn = mongoose.connect(dbRoute, { useNewUrlParser: true })`

Consider:

```
dbRoute = mongodb://DB-username:DBpassword@ds245901.mlab.com:44422/Database-Name";
```

Here is your data information

```
DB-username = Your database user name
DBpassword = Your database password
Database-Name = Your database name (which database you want to use)
```

Therefore, no need to connect to your desired database like this:

```
const db = conn.db('test_db');
```

Comment: where would i specify the dbname and collectionname for mongodb atlass

Comment: const dbRoute = 'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-bmihj.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';        Here <user> = username;  <password> = password; and test = DB name;

Comment: this works, but does not make any sense. i got this connection string before I even created a collection on my cluster.

Comment: This answer does not address part of the question about "collections". How do you specify the collection to use?